# Image(childview) corners are not getting round shape with in linear layout

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-custom-view

I need to design one widget

[image]

But I am not getting perfect corner shape from the right side.
Any better approach to get this widget.
Its spinner and image with background

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your layout looks like. But when I only use a text field inside of linear layout I just set the background of the text field to a shape with corners. Maybe you have to wrap the spinner and image into another linear layout and set its background.